# How to update ntext datacolumn with another column with ntext value

Tags: sql-server

```
TBL1

ID   Value
1    A
2    B
3    C

TBL2

ID   Value
1    
2    
3    

UPDATE TBL1
SET TBL1.ID= TBL2.ID
FROM
TBL1 t1
INNER JOIN TBL2 t2
ON t1.Value= t2.Value
WHERE t2.ID like '1'

ID - nvarchar(200)
Value - ntext
```

My purpose is to fill `TBL2` from `TBL1`

I cannot change the datatypes as the database is not my database.

When I wrote the above content, everything is supposed to be fine.

But I have this error message.

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
The data types ntext and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You purpose is to fill TBL2, but in your were filling tabl1 in your sample code .

And you want to set ID? Value?

try this?

```
UPDATE t2
SET    t2.VALUE = t1.VALUE
FROM   tbl2 t2
       LEFT JOIN tbl1 t1
         ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE TBL1
SET TBL1.ID= TBL2.ID
FROM
TBL1 t1
INNER JOIN TBL2 t2
ON CAST(t1.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST(t2.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
WHERE t2.ID like '1'
```

As per the error, SQL Server cannot compare NTEXT columns, but by turning these into NVARCHAR(MAX) a comparison can be performed.

On an unrelated note, the LIKE in the WHERE clause will be treated as = as there is no wildcard in the comparison string.

Answer (score 0):

This will [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/6bd4c661-ea0b-435f-af78-097e61549d41/) will explain the text and ntext comparision in detail